# Automation studio - Error in Query script

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, attribute

I'm running a query with the following structure
SELECT *
FROM [nameDE]
WHERE PersonhasOptoutOfEmail = No

I got an error message on the WHERE condition and I don't understand which is the issue. Probably the No is a wrong option, but I don't know which are the values for the boolean attribute PersonhasOptoutOfEmail.
May I ask if the structure of the query is correctly written and where I can see the values of this attribute? in the DE I only see it's a boolean. I thank in advance for your help, 
G.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT field1,field2 FROM [nameDE] WHERE PersonhasOptoutOfEmail = 0 . Can you try this?

Also review, if your target DE is correct and available.